# Re-structure using LODASH

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have been trying a few LoDash functions all day but couldn't get the right way to do this. Assigning a key `fill` to the parent array and also prepend with key `levelno` and each value of another array below `[1,2,3,4,5]`

```
[ [ { rect: 'R202',
   x: 163,
   y: 1393,
   width: 38,
   height: 17.5,
   grade: 'hf',
   accessible: false },
 { rect: 'R214',
   x: 163,
   y: 1445.5,
   width: 38,
   height: 17.5,
   grade: 'hf',
   accessible: false } ],
[ { rect: 'R202',
   x: 163,
   y: 1393,
   width: 38,
   height: 17.5,
   grade: 'hf',
   accessible: false },
 { rect: 'R214',
   x: 163,
   y: 1445.5,
   width: 38,
   height: 17.5,
   grade: 'hf',
   accessible: false } ] ]
```

with `[1,2,3,4,5]` into this

```
{ 'level: [{
    "levelno": 1,
    "fill": [
      { 
        rect: "R202",
        x: 163,
        y: 1393,
        width: 38,
        height: 17.5,
        grade: "hf",
        accessible: false 
      }, {
        rect: "R214",
        x: 163,
        y: 1445.5,
        width: 38,
        height: 17.5,
        grade: "hf",
        accessible: false
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "levelno": 2,
    "fill": [
      { 
        rect: "R202",
        x: 163,
        y: 1393,
        width: 38,
        height: 17.5,
        grade: "hf",
        accessible: false 
      }, {
        rect: "R214",
        x: 163,
        y: 1445.5,
        width: 38,
        height: 17.5,
        grade: "hf",
        accessible: false
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Are the level numbers always start at 1 and increment by 1, or is the level numbers array a must?

Comment: the lever numbers are provided and not necessarily incremented by 1. It could be `[3, 9, 11, 4]` and it could be string `['one', 'two', 'three']`

Comment: Thank you @OriDrori your solution works out pretty well and it more easier that I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use vanilla js [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or lodash's [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#map) to map each sub array to an object in the desired format:

```
function level(data, levels) {
  return {
    level: data.map(function(fill, index) {
       return {
         levelno: levels[index],
         fill: fill
       };
    })
  }; 
}
```

```js
function level(data, levels) {
  return {
    level: data.map(function(fill, index) {
       return {
         levelno: levels[index],
         fill: fill
       };
    })
  }; 
}

var data = [
  [{
    rect: 'R202',
    x: 163,
    y: 1393,
    width: 38,
    height: 17.5,
    grade: 'hf',
    accessible: false
  }, {
    rect: 'R214',
    x: 163,
    y: 1445.5,
    width: 38,
    height: 17.5,
    grade: 'hf',
    accessible: false
  }],
  [{
    rect: 'R202',
    x: 163,
    y: 1393,
    width: 38,
    height: 17.5,
    grade: 'hf',
    accessible: false
  }, {
    rect: 'R214',
    x: 163,
    y: 1445.5,
    width: 38,
    height: 17.5,
    grade: 'hf',
    accessible: false
  }]
];

var levels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var result = level(data, levels);

console.log(result);
```

The shorter ES6 version:

```
const level = (data, levels) => ({
  level: data.map((fill, index) => ({
    levelno: levels[index],
    fill
  }))
});
```